# How to trigger other cancellation tokens?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have two controllers, one provide a stream to download a file, the other allows the file to be deleted.

When a request to delete the file comes in, I'd like to interrupt the stream download (from disk) so that the file can be deleted.

I have tried combining cancellation tokens and storing them in an IMemoryCache.  Whilst I can retrieve the value and call the cancel on the CancellationTokenSource, it does not trigger the cancel on the other controller.

Is there some mechanism by which I can stop the streaming of the file in order to delete it?

The use-case is similar to YouTube in the sense that if the content creator wanted to delete their video, YouTube would let you watch what is already buffered, but not allow you to stream any more of the video once the delete request came in.

Edit: Adding code:

Delete:

```
var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove).SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
this.MemoryCache.Set(fileId, true, cacheEntryOptions);
```

My thought here is that the delete action will add something to the cache which the stream action can check for.

Stream action:

```
while (!response.HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested && bytesRemaining > 0)
{
    if (this.MemoryCache.TryGetValue(this.FileId, out bool dummyValue))
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException("Operation cancelled remotely");
    }
}
```

With `RequestAborted` I expect if the client makes their own cancellation request the stream will stop (which it does).

Surrounding the `while` I have a try/catch:

`catch (OperationCanceledException cancelled)`

Which is there to dispose of the file accessor.

I tried something similar with CancellationTokens and combining them using a TokenSource, but calling cancel seemed to do nothing at all.

The problem with the current approach is that there appears to be a situation in which the access to the file is not disposed when the delete action is called (even if within that call I sleep for 10 minutes).  If I make a subsequent call instead after a minute or so (without the 10 minute delay) then the file can be deleted.  It's confusing as to what is holding on to a lock to the file and I feel as though cancellation tokens would solve the problem here...

Comment: You're on the right track with memory cache. Want to show the code you've tried?

Comment: Youtube can do that because it is not really streaming the video. In reality you are doing get requests behind the scenes to get batched parts of the video you are watching.

Comment: I have updated the question is some code :)